# Getting error, use `yyyy` instead of `YYYY` (in `dd-MM-YYYY`) in php although i already format to 'yyyy'

Tags: php, reactjs, date, datetime

The current output of my date right now is something like this `13/01/2022`. The code uses `toDateString()` to format the `date`. Below are the full code.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use App\Models\AssetTimeslot;
use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class BookingResource extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array|\Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Arrayable|\JsonSerializable
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return array_merge(parent::toArray($request), [
            'timeslots' => $this->whenLoaded(
                'timeslots',
                fn () => $this->timeslots->map(fn (AssetTimeslot $assetTimeslot) => [
                    'id' => $assetTimeslot->id,
                    'name' => $assetTimeslot->name,
                    'date' => $assetTimeslot->pivot->date?->toDateString(),
                    'start_time' => $assetTimeslot->timeslot ? $assetTimeslot->timeslot->start_time : '',
                    'end_time' => $assetTimeslot->timeslot ? $assetTimeslot->timeslot->end_time : '',
                ])->groupBy('date')
            ),
        ]);
    }
}
```

What I've tried is by using this,

```
$orgDate = 'date',
$newDate = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($orgDate)),
$newDate2 = $newDate . "(dd-MM-yyyy)",
```

and hence, on `'date' => $assetTimeslot->pivot->date?->$newDate2,`. Even like this, I still get an error saying, `react-dom.development.js:12056 Uncaught RangeError: Use` yyyy`instead of`YYYY`(in`dd-MM-YYYY`) for formatting years to the input` Wed Mar 22 2023 08:00:00 GMT+0800 (Malaysia Time)`; see: https://github.com/date-fns/date-fns/blob/master/docs/unicodeTokens.md`. I've tried all the other methods but the same error remain especially by using the new Date() as suggested in the previous link.

The date is obtained from a picker calendar and when I've chosen a date, and look at the console, here are the date info of the date,
[image]

Comment: That's a javascript error, not a PHP error. It gives you [a nice link](https://github.com/date-fns/date-fns/blob/master/docs/unicodeTokens.md) that explains the problem, `YY and YYYY that represent the local week-numbering year (44, 01, 00, 17) are often confused with yy and yyyy that represent the calendar year.`

Comment: @aynber I've followed the suggestion as in the link, but everytime there is new Date() involved, i'll be getting an error.

Comment: Ignore the PHP code, it's probably not an issue here. Instead, look at your reactjs code for where you've got a format set.

Comment: @aynber as in my current code, the `'date' => $assetTimeslot->pivot->date?->toDateString(),` already showing the date format, e.g: 12/03/2022, but I want to change it to 12/March/2022

Comment: Are you using Laravel/Carbon? If so, that's not a standard format, so you'll need to [format it yourself](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-formatting)